# How long can we expect the approval process for a EV SSL cert to take?

Tags: ssl

Based on your experience, how long does it typically take to get a EV SSL cert approved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most take 2 or 3 working days or so after you submit all required documents; but it will depend on how easily your information is verified. EV Certs are not for those in a hurry, and telling them your in a hurry will raise red flags.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried contacting the vendor?  Very often the process can be stalled waiting on a particular person in the chain to get back to the SSL Provider.

My EV certs from Verisign only took a couple of days.